# Linux Mint 18.3 upgraded to 19 - Screen now distorts with open-vm-tools-desktop

Tags: linux-mint, x11, virtual-machine, vmware, display

Except this singular issue, everything works wonderfully. I already tried `apt-get purge open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop` but it didn't help.

#### This is what I'm seeing after upgrading. The Y coordinates of the mouse/elements on the screen are also no longer in sync.

[image]

#### And shrinking the size of the VMware Window results in this:

[image]

#### The OS gets the proper screen resolution reported, but resizes itself incorrectly:

[image]

Comment: Feel free to fill a [bugreport](https://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).